# Finding roots of complex polynomial with conjugates

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I am having problem with the following question...
I know that I should use De Moivre's formula somewhere... but can't quite get to it
$$ (-15w + 34\bar{w})^4 = -1 $$

will be happy to get some help,
Thanks!

Ron

Comment: Have you tried breaking it into two parts?  First solving for when $z^4 = -1$, and then for each solution finding $w$ such that $-15w+34\bar{w}=z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=a+ib\iff \bar w$

$$(19a-49ib)^4=1=e^{2n\pi i}$$ where $n$ is any integer

$19a+(-49b)i=e^{\dfrac{2n\pi i}4}$ where $n\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4$

Now for each case, equate the real & the imaginary parts

Comment: Can you explain the  $e^{2n\pi i}$ ?